# How to pick good contrast RGB colors programmatically?

Tags: colors, rgb

Suppose, in your program:

1. `color A` is a color we randomly select
2. Knowing `color A`, **how can I pick a `color B` that will be in high contrast with `color A`?**

The problem can be further reduced to: "imagine 2 squares filled with color next to one another. It should be **unambiguously clear to a human eye** that colors are not the same"

Example:

- Black --> White
- Blue --> White

Comment: you need to have contrast like oposite colors? Or how do you consider the "contrast" level? In your examples, you have "black" two times...

Comment: @woliverajr, I suppose, "opposite" is one way to look at it. Examples show famous xterm colors that look good (to most people) together

Comment: There is some definition about color contrast, take a look at the answer below. The http://www.lighthouse.org/accessibility/design/accessible-print-design/effective-color-contrast also has some interesting points about color contrast x good looking contrast.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically choose high-contrast colors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407793/programmatically-choose-high-contrast-colors)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is some information in the Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) 2.0 (http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211)

1. Visual contrast: http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#visual-audio-contrast-contrast
2. Contrast ratio: http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#contrast-ratiodef
3. Relative luminance : http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#relativeluminancedef

There's a good example [in this site](http://snook.ca/technical/colour_contrast/colour.html) but he calculate where two colors are enough, not how to get them.

To choose a color with good contrast, I'd go with complementary colors: for example, choose the random color A, transform it to a HSV space, get the complementary hue.

Complementary hue: after you transform color from RGB to HSV, complementary hue will be 180 degrees appart (or 0.5, in a 0-1 normalized hue value). [This site](http://serennu.com/colour/rgbtohsl.php) has something about it in PHP

Comment: By that explanation the complement of `0, 0, 0` (black) in HSV is `180, 0, 0` which is also black? Shouldn't it be `(180, 0, 100)` i.e. white? So luminance needs to be inverted as well?

Answer (score 4):

As I was searching for a better way to do this, i stumbled across the Adobe Illustrator guide which mentions how they create complementary colors. They say:

> Complement Changes each component of a color to a new value based on the sum of the highest and lowest RGB values in the selected color. Illustrator adds the lowest and highest RGB values of the current color, and then subtracts the value of each component from that number to create new RGB values. For example, suppose you select a color with an RGB value of 102 for red, 153 for green, and 51 for blue. Illustrator adds the high (153) and low (51) values, to end up with a new value (204). Each of the RGB values in the existing color is subtracted from the new value to create new complementary RGB values: 204 – 102 (the current red value) = 102 for the new red value, 204 – 153 (the current green value) = 51 for the new green value, and 204 – 51 (the current blue value) = 153 for the new blue value.

It wouldn't be too hard to do this programmatically and think this time that it might actually work for what you are trying to do.

Good Luck!

Comment: No. Think about having one color that is RGB(130, 130, 130). Having (125, 125, 125) won't be good... RGB isn't a good model to change the color, models having a HUE value are easier to deal with.

Comment: I see. Sorry for the incorrect answer. So would the correct thing to do be finding the Complementary color?

Comment: After the question was edited, I think it got easier, just need to be color that aren't too close to each other (in HUE values), not exactly complementary. You can edit your answer and sugest that.

Comment: I found an interesting post in adobes illustrator guide about how they calculate Complementary colors. I edited my post, here is the source link:http://livedocs.adobe.com/en_US/Illustrator/13.0/help.html?content=WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6288.html

Comment: It's almost good. If RGB (255, 255, 250), sum = 505, new values would be (250, 250, 255). Not very good ones.... The complementary color of almost white would be another almost white. A workaround for this method would be `if sum > 255, sum = 255`.

Comment: if rgb (0,0,0) this gives black again are there any more such edge cases? `if (sum == 0) sum = 255;`