# Determine font colour from background colour

Tags: user-interface, vb6, colors, color-scheme

I have been asked to modify a part of our software such that users can set the colour of buttons themselves. Unfortunately as all of our buttons have font colour black this makes about half of the possible colours illegible or at least not really what they should be. My question is therefore whether it is possible to analyse either the standard HTML HEX colours 000000 - FFFFFF or the longs VB uses to determine the most appropriate colour to use as a foreground given a background. (It only really needs to choose between black and white). I was thinking of trying to use getpixel and trying to convert colours to greyscale and determine the difference, any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What about also letting them choose the font color for themselves? if your changing the background color of a button changing the font color wouldn't be that much more work

Comment: that is what I might end up falling back on (and in fact what I am doing while I wait for a response here) but the number of buttons they have is quite large (up to 50) dynamic based on a text file and we are loading the colours from the text file, this means they keep having to close and reload our software to see any changes. I could make a timer to reload it, but I have come across issues like this before and it would be nice if I could at least have a sensible suggested colour (like I do for backgrounds) which the users could potentially override. So it would still be nice to have.

Comment: I could build an editor into the main software and probably will eventually but for now we do not want people to accidentally make all text invisible and be unable to get it back without calling support, so at least being able to catch really similar colours would be useful.

Comment: Just so you know, there is no need to put the tag in the title or add a signature. Both are already shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you google "rgb contrasting colors", you'll likely get a lot of good ideas. Here are some to try:

[How to pick good contrast RGB colors programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260989/how-to-pick-good-contrast-rgb-colors-programmatically)

http://devblog.famundo.com/articles/2006/06/14/finding-good-color-contrast

http://www.ehow.com/how_6577466_calculate-color-contrast.html