# Shift a color in order to obtain a specific contrast ratio

Tags: javascript, math, rgb, wcag2.0, high-contrast

Is there a way, given two colors (let's call them first color and second color) to figure out what color the second color must be changed to in order to obtain a contrast ratio of 4.5? In other words, what amount do we need to shift the second color in order to obtain a contrast ratio of 4.5? The luminance and ratio code are as follows:

**Luminance Code:**

```
function getLuminance (rgb){

    for (var i =0; i<rgb.length; i++) {
        if (rgb[i] <= 0.03928) {
            rgb[i] = rgb[i] / 12.92;    
        } else {
            rgb[i] = Math.pow( ((rgb[i]+0.055)/1.055), 2.4 );
        }
    }
    var l = (0.2126 * rgb[0]) + (0.7152 * rgb[1]) + (0.0722 * rgb[2]);
    return l;
};
```

**Ratio Code:**

```
var ratio = 1;
var l1 = getLuminance([first_color_red.value/255, first_color_green.value/255, first_color_blue.value/255]);
var l2 = getLuminance([second_color_red.value/255, second_color_green.value/255, second_color_blue.value/255]);

if (l1 >= l2) {
    ratio = (l1 + .05) / (l2 + .05);
} else {
    ratio = (l2 + .05) / (l1 + .05);
}
```

The problem i'm facing is with the luminance calculation - just based on a ratio, it seems like it is not possible to figure out the R, G and B values as they would be three unknowns (depends on which path each of the colors takes - is it greater than 0.03928 or not...).

We can add in more constraints by considering the color brightness and color difference calculations as shown below:

**Color Brightness Code:**
The threshold for brightnessDifference is that it is greater than or equal to 125.

```
fY=((first_color_r.value * 299) + (first_color_g.value * 587) + (first_color_b.value * 114)) / 1000;
sY=((second_color_r.value * 299) + (second_color_g.value * 587) + (second_color_b.value * 114)) / 1000;
brightnessDifference = Math.abs(fY-sY);
```

**Color Difference Code:**
The threshold for colorDifference is that it is greater than or equal to 500.

```
colorDifference = (Math.max (second_color_r.value, first_color_r.value) - Math.min (second_color_r.value, first_color_r.value)) +
                        (Math.max (second_color_g.value, first_color_g.value) - Math.min (second_color_g.value, first_color_g.value)) +
                        (Math.max (second_color_b.value, first_color_b.value) - Math.min (second_color_b.value, first_color_b.value));
```

I have read the following post: [How to pick good contrast RGB colors programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260989/how-to-pick-good-contrast-rgb-colors-programmatically)

However, calculating complementary colors may not always solve the problem! It may not even result in a contrast ratio of 4.5 ... Any ideas on how this may be accomplished?

Comment: This is not my area of expertise, but the fact that there are three unknowns would seem to imply that there are multiple degrees of freedom in producing an answer, i.e., you can shift the second color in many different ways to get a color satisfying your constraints.  Hence you may need more constraints to get a single answer.

Comment: We can add in more constraints by adding in a calculation for color brightness and color difference. I'll update the question to add those in