# Is it possible to make a Javascript program that changes the color of the text to the contrast of the background automatically?

Tags: javascript, html, colors, dom-events

I have this Javascript and HTML code which changes the color of the background using an input with the type of color.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    input {
      outline: none;
      border: none;
      background: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  Change the color of the background:
  <input type="color" value="#000000" name="bgcolor" id="bgcolor" />

  <script>
    const color = document.getElementById("bgcolor");

    color.addEventListener("change", () => {    
      document.body.style.background = color.value;
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

So this changes the color of the page's background as the user changes the color in the color palette created by the `<input type="color" value="#000000" name="bgcolor" id="bgcolor" />` .

Now imagine a situation in which the user selects black as the background and the text's color is by default also black now there are two things that we can do either,

Give an option to change the text's color him/herself or change the text's color to its background's contrast automatically.

I want to go for the second option since it is kinda fancier and looks a bit more advanced to the user like an extra advanced thing to impress the users.

So how do I implement the second option can someone explain it to me that how to change the color of the text to the complete contrast of the background automatically as the user sets the background.

Comment: A color like `#ff0000` means `FF` for red, and `00` for green and blue. You need to extract these values, parse them into 0-255 ints, then subtract each of them from 255 to get the contrast value. Now turn them back into hex, add them together and use that as text color.

Comment: I think this might solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35970186/14201528

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260989/how-to-pick-good-contrast-rgb-colors-programmatically this may solve your issue

Comment: Duplicate: [How can I generate the opposite color according to current color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969656/how-can-i-generate-the-opposite-color-according-to-current-color)

Comment: @ChrisG nope I think my situation is a bit different I don't want to convert it into rgb and then back to hex and stuff I did took a look into the answers but none helped.

Comment: @Vibhor Yes it did help me but still I am a bit stuck here wasn't able to understand some concepts

Comment: @secan nope sorry It did not

Comment: but thanks @everyone becasue all comments did help but the answer below was exactly what I wanted to do

Comment: How exactly is your situation different...? What else is `change the text's color to its background's contrast automatically.` supposed to mean then? The fact that you don't understand the code in existing answers doesn't mean your question isn't a dupe.

Comment: @ChrisG aight you may close my question but do note that the answer below solved my problem the other ones were simply not suiting my code and a lot of the part I wasn't able to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting resources for this:

- [W3C - Ensure that foreground and background color combinations provide sufficient contrast](http://www.w3.org/TR/AERT#color-contrast)
- [Calculating the Perceived Brightness of a Color](http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2008/04/27/Calculating-the-Perceived-Brightness-of-a-Color.aspx)

Here's the W3C algorithm (with [JSFiddle demo too](http://jsfiddle.net/PXJ2C/)):

```js
const rgb = [255, 0, 0];

// Randomly change to showcase updates
setInterval(setContrast, 1000);

function setContrast() {
  // Randomly update colours
  rgb[0] = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
  rgb[1] = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
  rgb[2] = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);

  // http://www.w3.org/TR/AERT#color-contrast
  const brightness = Math.round(((parseInt(rgb[0]) * 299) +
                      (parseInt(rgb[1]) * 587) +
                      (parseInt(rgb[2]) * 114)) / 1000);
  const textColour = (brightness > 125) ? 'black' : 'white';
  const backgroundColour = 'rgb(' + rgb[0] + ',' + rgb[1] + ',' + rgb[2] + ')';
  $('#bg').css('color', textColour); 
  $('#bg').css('background-color', backgroundColour);
}
```

```css
#bg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="bg">Text Example</div>
```