# Matlab graphics- Adaptively change font color depending on background colour

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, graphics2d

I have a heat map plot in MATLAB. However, the default text label on every box has the same font colour. This reduces readability.

How can I come up (MATLAB code/concept) with an adaptive font colouring scheme that reads the colour value of each box in the heat map, and automatically chooses a font colour that contrasts with the background?

I am happy to move to gnuplot/ggplot2/pgfplots/matplotlib if so required to achieve this

Comment: See the
[Programmatically choose high-contrast colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407793/programmatically-choose-high-contrast-colors)

Comment: There's an example of that here for grayscale data: [How do I visualize a matrix with colors and values displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3942892/52738) If you have color data, you could convert to grayscale (such as with `rgb2gray`) and apply the calculations there.